# Powershell return value of Cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Let's say I do this:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $search_base -filter {
     (GivenName -eq $firstname) -and (SN -eq $surname)
}
```

Doe this return the user object for true and if not found a simple $false?

Same question for the rest of the cmdlets

Comment: ... or checked the [cmdlet help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) which describes the return type?

Answer (score 3):

The verb Get in Get-ADUser signifies that it will return an ADUser (or $null). Cmdlets that return booleans ($true or $false) use the verb Test. The scriptblock you're passing as a filter is used to decide on which ADUser objects the cmdlet will return.